# I need help on this radio button

Tags: matlab, user-interface

What is the problem on this syntax? 
why I cannot set the values from specific radio button (Ch1-4)?

```
switch get(get(handles.uipanel4,'SelectedObject'),'Tag')

% --- Executes on button press in setF.
function setF_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to setF (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global hz;
hz=get(handles.editF, 'String');

if handles.Ch1 
    set(handles.fCh1, 'String', hz);

elseif handles.Ch2
    set(handles.fCh2, 'String', hz);

elseif handles.Ch3
    set(handles.fCh3, 'String', hz);

elseif handles.Ch4
    set(handles.fCh4, 'String', hz);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough to answer it well. What kind of problem do you get?

However, here is my guess:
what is `switch get(get(handles.uipanel4,'SelectedObject'),'Tag')` supposed to do? You start a switch statement, but never define the cases...
This should be causing syntax errors. So if you get any - this is what you should fix.
Take a look at the [switch syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html).

I will be happy to modify my answer if you provide more info.